# How to calculate this sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I have something in my Notes states that:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}e^{2\pi i(2n+1)x} = 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}cos(2\pi (2n+1)x)$.

I am wondering how did this work? Shouldn't it be something like

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}e^{2\pi i(2n+1)x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}(cos(2\pi (2n+1)x)+isin(2\pi (2n+1)x))$?

and the range of x is $x\in [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: If you take $x=0$ then you will notice that the $2$ placed right after $=$ should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

By demoivre's theorem $(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^n=\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)$ so we can write $e^{i2\pi(2n+1)x}=(\cos(2\pi(2n+1)x)+i\sin(2\pi(2n+1)x))$. Now as $sin(2\pi(2n+1)x)$ approaches $1/2,0$ the expression also goes to $0$ . I have done it as $|x|\leq 1$ . Thus we can ignore that sin term as it becomes negligible giving only $\cos$

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that x is not an integer. You can see my edit

Comment: thanks for your update. I don't understand why  $e^{i2\pi(2n+1)x}=(\cos(2\pi(2n+1)x)+i\sin(2\pi(2n+1)x))^x$ ? I mean why x times the right hand side?

Comment: Sorry wrongly left it

Comment: Hope its clear now

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand... Why $sin(2\pi (2n+1)x)$ approaches $ \frac{1}{2}$? and which expression goes to 0? Note that x is any number between $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: No for those two values $1/2 ,0$ the whole $sin(2\pi(2n+1)x)$ goes to $0$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar The OP wrote an identity.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Okay... But why should I consider when  $x=\frac{1}{2}$ or $x=0$? Bear with me I'm really not good at math

Comment: I said that as $x$ approaches smaller and smaller values the sin starts becoming negligible